# hide form select fields based on select value from the homepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a booking form on my website and if I select 10+ people the form options for a booth disappear because they only hold a max of 9 people. This is all working and here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form1_people').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="10+ People"){
    $("#tenplus").hide()
        $("#booth-notice").show()
    }
    else{
    $("#tenplus").show()
        $("#booth-notice").hide()
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is on the homepage I have a quick booking form that when the user fills it out and it autoupdates the large form. But if I select 10+ people from the homepage the JavaScript doesn't execute.

I thought I needed to have this JavaScript on every page? I tried this but it doesn't work. I'm out of ideas. Anyone?

Thanks

UPDATE!!!!

```
                <div>
            <label for="form1_people">How many people:</label>
                <select id="form1_people" name="people" class="venue-select">
                    <option value="Select how many people">Select how many people</option>
                    <option value="2 People">2 People</option>
                    <option value="3 People">3 People</option>
                    <option value="4 People">4 People</option>
                    <option value="5 People">5 People</option>
                    <option value="6 People">6 People</option>
                    <option value="7 People">7 People</option>
                    <option value="8 People">8 People</option>
                    <option value="9 People">9 People</option>
                    <option value="10 People">10 People</option>
                    <option value="10+ People">10+ People</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div id="booth-notice" style="display:none;">
                <label style="color: #ed1c24!important; font-size: 16px!important; line-height: 1.4em!important;"><em style="color: #ed1c24!important;">Customer Notice * Booths are not available for parties with more than 10 people</em></label>
            </div>

            <div id="tenplus"><!-- HIDE THESE IF THERE IS MORE THAN 10 PEOPLE -->           
                <div>
                    <label for="form1_booth">Would you like a Booth: <em>*Liverpool &amp; Manchester Only</em> <a href="#">What's this?</a></label>
                    <select id="form1_booth" name="booth" class="venue-select">
                        <option value="Please select an option">Please select an option</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="form1_booth-package">We have some Booth Packages <a href="#">What's this?</a></label>
                    <select id="form1_booth-package" name="booth-package" class="venue-select">
                        <option value="Select an option if wanting a booth">Select an option if wanting a booth</option>
                        <option value="Bier Package">Bier Package</option>
                        <option value="Cocktail Package">Cocktail Package</option>
                        <option value="Just a booth please">Just a booth please</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div><!-- HIDE THESE IF THERE IS MORE THAN 10 PEOPLE -->
```

Comment: Can you paste the html for this form?

Comment: Are you sure the option value is 100% identical to `10+ People`?

Comment: Did you try to use "==" instead of "===", or the Javascript doesn't come to that point? What you mean saying the Javascript doesn't execute? Is it giving any error?

Comment: I have updated the post with the HTML. Like I said this code is working fine when on the booking page. Its when I'm on the homepage filling out the quick form when the JavaScript doesn't execute?

Comment: 1) I'd check errors with Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools. 2) I'd put a simple alert to see if it's passing from there. 3) I'd check the ID of the quick booking form, to be sure it's not called #form1_people".

Comment: I'm thinking the form needs to be in a query string? But the form isn't set up like this. I have a test version of the website here [link](http://newsite.thebierkeller.com/bookings/)

Comment: I think you're not correctly reading the combo value with number of people when you post from home to booking page, so the problem is probably before your javascript. I tried and it's reading date&location correctly, but it's not the same for the people number.

Comment: I have just noticed this, so I have updated this and is now back working with the correct number of people showing but the other fields are not hiding :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change something in your logic and I'll explain now what I'd do.

Your JavaScript is correctly written but it's called only when the "change" event occurs. So, when the page is loaded after your post from the homepage the select value has already been changed and your function won't be called.

You could do something like this. It's not very elegant but it can do your job:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    boothUpdate(); // This function is called at every page load
    $('#form1_people').on('change',function(){
        boothUpdate(); // This function is called at every select change
    });    
});

function boothUpdate() {
    if( $(this).val()==="10+ People"){
        $("#tenplus").hide()
        $("#booth-notice").show()
    }
    else {
        $("#tenplus").show()
        $("#booth-notice").hide()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me, the whole script didn't work and the browser brought up no errors.

Comment: I suggest you to put some debug alert to see if it's passing from there, before the first boothUpdate() call for example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this by adding `.trigger('change');` at the end of the function.

Full working script here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#form1_people').on('change',function(){
        if( $(this).val()=="10+ People"){
            $("#tenplus").hide()
            $("#booth-notice").show()
        }
        else{
            $("#tenplus").show()
            $("#booth-notice").hide()
       }
   }).trigger('change');
});
```

Thanks everyone for the help...